# Having trouble scaling scores of logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, scoring

I am constructing a credit scorecard using logistic regression, similar to the one shown [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-credit-scorecard-9afeaaa3725f). However, when trying to convert the coefficients of logistic regression into score representation (by scaling the values using the provided formula) I am getting numbers that dont make much sense.

Formula used for calculating scores:

**Score_i= (βi × WoE_i + α/n) × Factor + Offset/n**

- where **βi** is the coefficient of the logistic regression (of variable `i`),
- **WoE_i** is the [weight of evidence](https://www.listendata.com/2015/03/weight-of-evidence-woe-and-information.html#Steps-of-Calculating-WOE) of corresponding variable,
- **α** is the intercept of the logistic regression,
- **Factor** is calculated as `PDO / ln(2)`,
- **Offset** is calculated as `target_points - (factor * ln(target_odds))`
- **n** is number of variables used in regression

In my case PDO = 50, target_odds = 2, target_points = 500, n = 81, and intercept is -0.12686514.

Here is an example of one of my features:

[image: example 1]

As it can be seen, both WoE and the coefficients increase in value as the "revenue" variable increases. The score however does not act in this way. Initially I just assumed the scores acted in inverse proportion to those two values so I added a negative sign in front of the formula:

**Score_i= -(βi × WoE_i + α/n) × Factor + Offset/n**

But for some other features, the score is proportional to the other values:

[image]

And adding the negative sign would now make this feature have a score that does not make much sense.

How can I keep the scaling consistent? What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using a wrong formula for scaling the scores. The formula

**Score_i= (βi × WoE_i + α/n) × Factor + Offset/n**

is applicable only if the logistic regression is done after doing WoE Transform, meaning for all features (not for all bins!) a WoE value is assigned and then the classifier is fit.

The way I was doing it was binning first, and feeding columns with dummy values into the classifier.

[Reference to correct approach](https://tinyurl.com/yxojd3va)